# Passing data between different components. vue 3.2

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to refresh component data from another component.

I have components folder and Pages folder where I use this components.

- component A
- component B
- component C

In component A I send post qvuery.

```
<script setup>

import {ref} from "vue";

let props = defineProps({
    param: Array,
});

function sendPost(){
axios.post('url',{param}).then(function (response) {
    if (response.data.success) {

/*response data send to component B*/

    } else {
        //show warning
    }
}).catch(function (error){

})
}
</script>
```

Then I want to send data from response to component B. What I need to do please to achieve it ? I want dynamicaly refresh component B without page reload.

I try to use defineEmits, but it dose not help.

**Component 1.**

```
<template>
    <MainLayout title="Access Groups" :sidebar="true">
        <main class="main main-p">
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="main-head">
                    <ul class="breadcrumbs">
                        <li class="breadcrumbs-item">
                            <a href="#" class="breadcrumbs-link">
                                <i class="ico-home"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="breadcrumbs-item">
                            <a href="#" class="breadcrumbs-link">Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="breadcrumbs-item">
                            <a href="#" class="breadcrumbs-link">Assets groups</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <h1 class="main-head__title">Access Groups</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="main-actions">
                    <div class="main-actions__wrap">
                        <div class="main-actions__btns">
                            <a href="#modalCreateAccessNewGroup" class="btn btn-bordered" data-toggle="modal">
                                <i class="ico-plus"></i>
                                Create group
                            </a>
                            <button class="btn btn-light">
                                Delete
                                <i class="ico-delete"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main-body">
                    <div class="table">
                        <div class="table-head">
                            <div class="table-head__wrap">
                                <div class="table-head__item table-head__item-checkbox">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" id="checkboxGroupNameAll">
                                        <label for="checkboxGroupNameAll" class="checkbox-label"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="table-head__item">Group name</div>
                                <div class="table-head__item table-head__item-btn"></div>
                                <div class="table-head__item table-head__item-btn"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-body">
                            <div class="table-body__wrap">
                                <AccessGroup :access_groups="access_groups" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </MainLayout>
    <CreateNewAccessGroupModal :permissions_param="permissions_param" />
</template>
```

**Component 2.**

```
<template>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalCreateAccessNewGroup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalCreateNewGroup" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Create new group</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="ico-close"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <form @submit.prevent="createNewAccessGroup">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="modal-box">
                            <div class="modal-hold">
                                <div class="input">
                                    <label class="input-label">Group name:</label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input v-model="group_name" type="text" class="input-field">
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">Required field</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input">
                                    <label class="input-label">Description:</label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input v-model="description" type="text" class="input-field">
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">Required field</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="attribute">
                                <div class="attribute-head">Permissions</div>
                                <div v-for="(permission, index) in permissions_param" :key="index" class="attribute-body">
                                    <div class="attribute-row">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input v-model="permissions" :value="index" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" :id="index">
                                            <label :for="index" class="checkbox-label"></label>
                                        </div>
                                        {{permission.label}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer modal-footer__end">
                        <div class="modal-text">
                            By clicking save button API key for the group will be generated
                        </div>
                        <button id="close" class="btn btn-m-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-m-primary">Save Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

**Component 3**

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(access_group, index) in access_groups" :key="index" class="table-row">
        <div class="table-row__item table-row__item-checkbox">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" id="checkboxGroupName1">
                <label for="checkboxGroupName1" class="checkbox-label"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row__item">
            <span class="table-row__item-box">{{access_group.group_name}}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="table-row__item table-row__item-btn">
            <a href="#modalViewUsers" class="btn btn-m-secondary"
               data-toggle="modal">Users</a>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row__item table-row__item-btn">
            <a href="#modalEditAccessGroup" class="btn btn-m-secondary" data-toggle="modal">
                Details
                <i class="ico-edit"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <EditAccessGroupModal/>
    <ViewAccessGroupUsersModal/>
</template>
```

Comment: do the components share a parent?  emits (data goes from child to parent) and props (data goes from parent to child) can send data between any components that can be linked by child-parent relationships.  otherwise you need to manage some globally accessible state like with localStorage, provide/inject, or Pinia (Vue's official state management library).  you say you tried defineEmits but don't show in your code snippet how you tried to use it.  if you include your attempt then others can maybe show how to fix it.

Comment: Can you share all the 3 components code..

Comment: Sujith Sandeep, I added all the 3 components code. I try to refresh data at component 3 when I get post answer from component 2.

Comment: yoduh, could you show some example please according my templates. I need to send data from component Component 2 to Component 3 after post request.